# spin_lock.h port from windows to linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have the following header:

```
#if !defined(_SPIN_LOCK_H_INCLUDED_)
#define _SPIN_LOCK_H_INCLUDED_

#include <windows.h>

class spin_lock
{
public:
    spin_lock();
    virtual ~spin_lock();

    void lock( void );
    void unlock( void );

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;

    spin_lock( const spin_lock& that );
    const spin_lock& operator = ( const spin_lock& that );
};
```

There is a possibility to port this on Linux with minimum changes ?

After I comment  I'm getting this error:

In file included from ../sources/utils.11.0/MyPDFLibUtils.cpp:43:0:
    ../sources/utils.11.0/spin_lock.h:39:2: error: ‘CRITICAL_SECTION’ does            not name a type
      CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;

CRITICAL_SECTION is declared in WinBase.h part of Microsoft SDK

This is the implementation:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include "spin_lock.h"

spin_lock::spin_lock()
{
    ::InitializeCriticalSection( &m_lock );
}

spin_lock::~spin_lock()
{
    ::DeleteCriticalSection( &m_lock );
}

void spin_lock::lock( void )
{
    ::EnterCriticalSection( &m_lock );
}

void spin_lock:: unlock( void )
{
    ::LeaveCriticalSection( &m_lock );
}
```

Comment: There is no CRITICAL_SECTION in linux. You may need to use spin lock in pthread http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_spin_lock.html, Or atomic boolean flag for c++11

Comment: It would help an awful lot to understand how this was used. But you should be able to substitute a mutex directly.

Comment: Win32 critical sections are not spin locks either, so the class name is misleading. They are spinlocks with a maximum spin count that fall back to _blocking on a Nt keyed event_. As such, they are functionally identical to Linux futex  (not semantically, however, since waking a futex does not block whereas on the other hand waiting on a keyed event does not check the value).

Comment: Thank you for your help.